# Small mammal identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, teeth, rodents

Small skull found in Alberta, Canada. Do not know the region. Skull is about 17 mm in length. Trying to identify the species, narrowed it down to most like a species of vole but can't figure out which one. Below are pictures of the teeth under a dissecting microscope that we were using to ID, upper jaw and then lower jaw respectively.

[image: upper jaw teeth]

[image: lower jaw teeth]